# How do I remove blank rows created in longtable?

Tags: color, longtable, xstring

When I try to color a row inside `xstring` it created unwanted blank row, I need `longtable` for large data, so how do I proceed to filter out?

Here is my MWE:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{longtable,filecontents,datatool,xstring}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

 \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
 Sl.No., Name, Class, Gender
 1, Mr. David , X, M
 2, Miss Kache , XII,F
 3, Mr. Stephan, XII,M
 4, Mr. Prakash, XII,M
 5, Mr. Digvijay, XII,M
 \end{filecontents*}
 \DTLloaddb{mydata}{data.csv}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|}
 \hline
 Sl.No. & Name & Class & Gender\\ \hline
 \DTLforeach*{mydata}{\sl=Sl.No.,\name=Name,\c=Class,\g=Gender}{

 \IfStrEq{\g}{M}{\\\rowcolor{red!20} \sl & \name & \c & \g \\ \hline}{}

 }


 \end{longtable}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\rowcolor` like `\multicolumn` has to be the first thing (after expansion) in the row, you can not use `IfStrEq{`

Comment: Is there any alternative to \rowcolor so that i can use IfStrEq and color a row @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misplaced the `\hline`s and the `\\`s. Here is a cleaned up version

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{longtable,filecontents,datatool,xstring}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

 \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
 Sl.No., Name, Class, Gender
 1, Mr. David , X, M
 2, Miss Kache , XII,F
 3, Mr. Stephan, XII,M
 4, Mr. Prakash, XII,M
 5, Mr. Digvijay, XII,M
 \end{filecontents*}
 \DTLloaddb{mydata}{data.csv}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|}
 \hline
 Sl.No. & Name & Class & Gender  \DTLforeach*{mydata}{\sl=Sl.No.,\name=Name,\c=Class,\g=Gender}{%
 \IfStrEq{\g}{M}{\\\hline\rowcolor{red!20} \sl & \name & \c & \g }{}
 }\\\hline


 \end{longtable}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand I suggest a removal of the vertical separator, and the 1st, 3rd and 4th columns centered. In this example I also included the other line, which is filtered out in your example (just for completeness sake, since how not to render it is shown above)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{longtable,filecontents,datatool,xstring}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

 \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
 Sl.No., Name, Class, Gender
 1, Mr. David , X, M
 2, Miss Kache , XII,F
 3, Mr. Stephan, XII,M
 4, Mr. Prakash, XII,M
 5, Mr. Digvijay, XII,M
 \end{filecontents*}
 \DTLloaddb{mydata}{data.csv}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{clcc}
 \hline
 Sl.No. & Name & Class & Gender  \DTLforeach*{mydata}{\sl=Sl.No.,\name=Name,\c=Class,\g=Gender}{%
 \IfStrEq{\g}{M}{\\\hline\rowcolor{red!20} \sl & \name & \c & \g }{\\\hline\rowcolor{blue!20} \sl & \name & \c & \g}
 }\\\hline


 \end{longtable}

 \end{document}
```

[image]