# How do I remove extra row generated in longtable?

Tags: longtable, datatool, xstring

I don't know why this happen in longtable its generated extra row at the bottom of the table which is unwanted row, Please somebody help me to solved this problem here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[left=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{datatool}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,xstring,datatool,xintexpr,longtable} %for including eps graphics
 \usepackage{multirow,colortbl,xfp}


\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
ID,Name,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December
ABC01,Mr. ABC,1,3432,54,54,54,56,54,54,54,54,54,54.25
ABC02,Mr. ABC,2,354,234,234,234,80,234,234,234,234,234,234
ABC03,Mr. ABC,1,544,343,343,343,0,343,343,343,343,343,343
ABC04,Mr. ABC,0,3423,343,343,0,0,343,343,343,343,343,343
ABC05,Mr. ABC,1,34,434,434,0,0,434,434,434,434,434,434
ABC06,Mr. ABC,2,0,42,42,0,0,42,42,42,42,42,42
ABC07,Mr. ABC,25,0,3432,3432,0,0,3432,3432,3432,3432,3432,3432
ABC08,Mr. ABC,23,0,343,343,343,0,343,343,343,343,343,343
ABC09,Mr. ABC,12,0,43,43,43,0,43,43,43,43,43,43
ABC10,Mr. ABC,0,0,90,90,90,0,90,90,90,90,90,90
     ,Mr. ABC,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
     ,Mr. ABC,44,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
\end{filecontents}
\newcounter{Serial}
\newcounter{SerialN}

 \DTLloaddb{name}{data.csv}
\begin{document}



\centering


\edef\numberofrows{\DTLrowcount{name}}%
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{January}{\JanT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{February}{\FebT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{March}{\MarT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{April}{\AprT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{May}{\MayT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{June}{\JunT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{July}{\JulT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{August}{\AugT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{September}{\SepT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{October}{\OctT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{November}{\NovT}
\DTLsumcolumn{name}{December}{\DecT}


\begin{longtable}{|c|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{green!20}\bf\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{1mm}Sl.~No.} & \bf{\raisebox{3.5ex}{Name}} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{January}& \bf\rotatebox{90}{February}& \bf\rotatebox{90}{March} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{April}&\bf\rotatebox{90}{May} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{June} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{July} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{August} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{September}& \bf\rotatebox{90}{October} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{November} & \bf\rotatebox{90}{December}& \bf{\raisebox{4ex}{Total}}\\\hline \endhead

\DTLforeach*{name}{\name=Name,\jan=January,\feb=February,\mar=March,\apr=April,\may=May,\jun=June,\jul=July,\aug=August,\sep=September,\oct=October,\nov=November,\dec=December,\id=ID}{% build table


\IfSubStr{\id}{DBC}{\stepcounter{Serial}}{}
\IfInteger{\theSerial}{\stepcounter{SerialN}}{}

\theSerialN &\name&\jan&\feb&\mar&\apr&\may&\jun&\jul&\aug&\sep&\oct&\nov&\dec&\\\hline
}\\\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\it Total} & \JanT&\FebT&\MarT&\AprT&\MayT&\JunT&\JulT&\AugT&\SepT&\OctT&\NovT&\DTLtrunc{\result}{\DecT}{2}\result& \\     \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `\\ ` before your first `\bottomrule` and that as well.

Comment: No its not working its give me error with red text ! Misplaced \noalign.@TeXnician

Comment: Well, that's because your DTLforeach is treated as the first element (first column) in that new row.

Comment: How do I solve that row @TeXnician ?

Comment: isn't this identical to the question you asked yesterday? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370077/how-do-i-remove-blank-rows-created-in-longtable

Comment: Yes its similar but the coding is confussion so could not tackle the problem, however after searching through text.stackexchange, i found with good solution \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\\hline} https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42554/datatool-with-longtable    @DavidCarlisle